# Filter django admin list with text input

Tags: django, django-modeladmin

Based on [django ModelAdmin document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/filters/#using-a-field-name-and-an-explicit-fieldlistfilter) for filterize list data, exist some class in admin that making filters, like `DateFieldListFilter`, `ChoicesFieldListFilter` and etc,
But dosent exist any class for text input field.

I need to use several text input fields for filter my model list data in admin page.
What can i do?

Comment: Django admin pages already have the functionality you asked for. There is an input at the top of the list with a search button that applies filters to the fields you have defined. Am I missing something?

Comment: i have many fields, and  when i use search, its caused heavy query and give many time to process

Comment: If your query is taking a long time to process you need to utilize `select_related` and `prefetch_related`

Answer (score 0):

Something explained here would be helpful
https://hakibenita.com/how-to-add-a-text-filter-to-django-admin

```
class InputFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    template = "admin/input_filter.html"

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        # Dummy, required to show the filter.
        return ((),)

    def choices(self, changelist):
        # Grab only the "all" option.
        all_choice = next(super().choices(changelist))
        all_choice["query_parts"] = (
            (k, v)
            for k, v in changelist.get_filters_params().items()
            if k != self.parameter_name
        )
        yield all_choice
```

and you need to override template

```html
<!-- templates/admin/input_filter.html -->

{% load i18n %}

<h3>{% blocktrans with filter_title=title %} By {{ filter_title }} {% endblocktrans %}</h3>
<ul>
  <li>
    <form method="GET" action="">
        <input
           type="text"
           value="{{ spec.value|default_if_none:'' }}"
           name="{{ spec.parameter_name }}"/>
    </form>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**usage**

```
class UIDFilter(InputFilter):
    parameter_name = 'uid'
    title = _('UID')

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.value() is not None:
            uid = self.value()

            return queryset.filter(
                Q(uid=uid) |
                Q(payment__uid=uid) |
                Q(user__uid=uid)
            )
```

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/hakib/1491a848e71078dae81fca48c46cc258/raw/19934611bcdd6d806aabaf00f55f582cd40fffd8/input_filter.html

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/hakib/1491a848e71078dae81fca48c46cc258/raw/19934611bcdd6d806aabaf00f55f582cd40fffd8/admin.py

---

all credits to owner of this post